# grep: search once for different pattern and output to several files

Tags: bash, file-io, grep

Is it possible to tell grep to use different output files for every type of matching search string?

I need to search all *.log recursively to find all "[ERROR]", "[WARN]" and "[ASSERT]". But I would like to have it separated in different output files. One output file for each search string. (without calling grep several times!)

searching already works: (called from gmake)

```
grep -nHr --include=*.log -e '\[ERROR\]' -e '\[WARN\]' -e '\[ASSERT\]' $(root_path) > $(root_path)/result.txt
```

But due to performance I do not want to call grep several times:

```
grep -nHr --include=*.log -e '\[ERROR\]' $(root_path) > $(root_path)/result_[ERROR].txt

grep -nHr --include=*.log -e '\[WARN\]' $(root_path) > $(root_path)/result_[WARN].txt
```

Is it possible to have it somehow like:

```
grep -nHr --include=*.log -e {'PATTERN1' | 'PATTERN2' | 'PATTERN3'} $(root_path) > $(root_path)/result{'PATTERN1'|'PATTERN2'|'PATTERN3'}.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read thru the file in 1 pass, and write to multiple outFiles, I would use `awk`

```
  awk '/^\[Error\]/ {print FILENAME ":" NR ":" $0 > "errorFile.txt" }
       /^\[Warn\]/ {print FILENAME ":" NR ":" $0 > "warnFile.txt" }
       /Assert/ {print FILENAME ":" NR ":" $0 > "assertFile.txt" }'  logFile
```

You can gain a minor increase in speed, if you know for certain that the Error/Warn/Assert tokens are always the first on the line of interest and use the beginning-of-line reg-exp char (`^`), ie.

```
/^Error/ {print $0 > "errorFile.txt"
```

Comment: The string "[WARN]" and "[ERROR]" are indeed always at the start of a line in the log but the "ASSERT" string might be anywhere.

Comment: And I like the -nH options of grep: -H, --with-filename       print the filename for each match; -n, --line-number         print line number with output lines

Comment: This look promising but why does $0 not print the whole line?

Comment: in `awk`  `$0` by definition is the whole line. If you're not seeing everything, it means there are unusual chars in your logs OR that the info is split across more than one line. Won't be able to help with that, as it sounds very unpredictable.

Comment: The line has [] and spaces. Like: "[WARN][READBACK_HANDLER]: Cannot suspend counted readback handler"

Comment: post a separate Q with a 3 line sample that illustrates good data and bad data. Also take the time to read (and absorb) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed -n '{
/\[ERROR\]/w errorlog
/\[WARN\]/w warnlog
/\[ASSERT\]/w assertlog
}' $(  find /your/path/here -type f -name "*.log" )
```

may work for you.

Comment: This results in an error: sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'.

Comment: And I want to run it from the makefile which has a problem with the $ before the find:  ...assertlog
}' $(  find / ...

Comment: You will get unmatched `{` error, if you try to put all of the above in one line.

Comment: `which has a problem with the $ before the find:` - this error might be related to `unmatched {`.  Split the sed script to different lines as I have done and you may get through. @schwdk