# sed option to append matched pattern to file

Tags: bash, sed

sed [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) says :

> The file will be created (or truncated) before the first input line is
>   read; all w commands (including instances of the w flag on successful
>   s commands) which refer to the same filename are output without
>   closing and reopening the file.

So when I do :

```
sed '/pattern/w filename' file
```

The existing content in the file is deleted which is not good when I am dealing with log files.

How to make sed `w` option append content to a file instead of truncating it?

If a straight forward method is not available, any small tweaks are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought there was an `w >>file` option for sed, but I can't find it anywhere.

You can get what  you need with a similar construct in `awk`. i.e.

```
     awk -v outFile=/p/2/f/outfile '/pattern/{print $0 >> outFile }' inFile
```

IHTH

Comment: @sjsam : LoL, I see  I don't need to refer you to my expanded awk example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184036/grep-search-once-for-different-pattern-and-output-to-several-files/34184283#34184283 . ;-) Good luck to al.

Comment: @shelter : Appreciated. In a sense, it is that question that lead me here. ;)

Comment: Actually `w>>file` didn't throw an error. Just that it didn't work as expected.   Had it been implemented, it would have been pretty handy.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/pattern/w/dev/stdout' file1 >>file2
```

This will append each line in file1 containing `pattern` to file2.

An alternative:

```
sed -n '/pattern/s/.*/echo "&" >>file2/e' file1
```

Comment: The objective is not to use `>>` because I might be writing to more than one file as mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184036/grep-search-once-for-different-pattern-and-output-to-several-files/34184283#34184283) question.

Comment: `w/dev/stdout` !! Very devious! Well done. Good luck to all.